# Rewrite rule for nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, trac, static-files

I'm trying to deploy [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) with nginx. I almost have everything working exept for the rewrite rule for serving static files. I need to rewrite this url:

http://trac.domain.tldn/chrome/common/feed.png

to this one:

http://trac.domain.tldn/static/htdocs/common/feed.png

I have this code, but it isn't working:

```
    location ~ /(.*?)/chrome/common/ {
            rewrite /(.*?)/chrome/common/(.*) /$1/static/htdocs/common/$2 break;
            root    /var/www/domain.tldn/static/trac/static/htdocs/common;
    }
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: The Trac Nginx documentation needs to be improved, particularly for [serving static files](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracNginxRecipe#StaticContent). I hope to do a rewrite soon, but the answer by @dmitriy-z looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the following code:

```
location /chrome/common {
    rewrite ^/chrome/common/(.*) /static/htdocs/common/$1 permanent;
}
```

Or just use an alias for your files path:

```
location /chrome/common {
    alias /var/www/domain.tldn/static/trac/static/htdocs/common;
}
```

Comment: Depending on whether you have plugins installed and site-specific templates, Trac may also serve files from `/chrome/<plugin>` and `/chrome/site`, so you may want to use just `/chrome/` in the `location` directive and strip `/common` from the `alias` directive.